# What types of data can be represented in dot density map?

Tags: mapping, visualisation

I was creating a dot density map for GDP data of African countries. When I submitted the map I got feedback as "this map is incorrect in terms of visualization of data being used"
[image]

Each dots means 100 US$. Counting the dots on the map we can calculate the tentative GDP of the country easily. Dots are denser in countries with high GDP where as they are sparse in countries with low GDP. I am wondering how is the map incorrect in term of visualization of data being used?

Comment: A choroplethic map is probably a better way to symbolize quantitative data. Random dot density implies a level of precision to the location of GDP sources, and few will actually count the dots in large smudges. Unfortunately, this question is more cartography-centered than GIS-centric and much more *opinion-based* and *discussion-oriented* than the GIS SE Q&A model supports.

Comment: "Dots are denser in countries with high GDP where as they are sparse in countries with low GDP."  If two countries had the same GDP and the same population but vastly different land areas wouldn't the density of dots differ?  Look at Congo and Burundi on your map.  They look to have 3 or 4 dots each but they are denser in Burundi.